# Laravel passport get Client ID from auth()->user() object

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Is there a simple way to get the passport client that granted an access token from the `auth()->user()`. If not get the client from the access token?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can get client id from Laravel Auth object:

```
 $client_id = auth()->user()->Token()->getAttribute('client_id');
```